# How to make a 3 pictureboxes apear one after another with an interval of 500 ms

Tags: vb.net

I am making a slot machine and I have come across a problem. I want the 3 pictureboxes that say 777 appear one after another when I click on go. and I do not know how to do that

Here's my code in case someone needs to see it: ( I know it is not very good but I'm a beginner)

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dixmille As Integer
    Dim mille As Integer
    Dim cinqcent As Integer

    dixmille = 10500
    mille = 1500
    cinqcent = 500

    Randomize()
    Label1.Text = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 6))
    Label2.Text = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 6))
    Label3.Text = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 6))

    Timer1.Start()

    Timer1.Stop()

    Timer1.Start()

    Timer1.Stop()

    Timer1.Start()

    Timer1.Stop()

    ' 777 = 1
    ' bell = 2
    ' bar = 3
    ' cherries = 4
    ' diamond = 5
    ' grappes = 6


    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Coin, AudioPlayMode.Background)


    If Label1.Text = "1" Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources._777
    If Label2.Text = "1" Then PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources._777
    If Label3.Text = "1" Then PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources._777

    If Label1.Text = "2" Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.bell
    If Label2.Text = "2" Then PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.bell
    If Label3.Text = "2" Then PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.bell

    If Label1.Text = "3" Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.bar
    If Label2.Text = "3" Then PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.bar
    If Label3.Text = "3" Then PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.bar

    If Label1.Text = "4" Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.cherries
    If Label2.Text = "4" Then PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.cherries
    If Label3.Text = "4" Then PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.cherries

    If Label1.Text = "5" Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.diamond
    If Label2.Text = "5" Then PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.diamond
    If Label3.Text = "5" Then PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.diamond

    If Label1.Text = "6" Then PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.grappes
    If Label2.Text = "6" Then PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.grappes
    If Label3.Text = "6" Then PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.grappes


    If Label1.Text = "1" And Label2.Text = "1" And Label3.Text = "1" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + dixmille Else 
    If Label1.Text = "2" And Label2.Text = "2" And Label3.Text = "2" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + dixmille Else 
    If Label1.Text = "3" And Label2.Text = "3" And Label3.Text = "3" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + dixmille Else 
    If Label1.Text = "4" And Label2.Text = "4" And Label3.Text = "4" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + dixmille Else 
    If Label1.Text = "5" And Label2.Text = "5" And Label3.Text = "5" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + dixmille Else 
    If Label1.Text = "6" And Label2.Text = "6" And Label3.Text = "6" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + dixmille Else 

    If Label1.Text = "1" And Label2.Text = "1" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + mille Else 
    If Label1.Text = "2" And Label2.Text = "2" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + mille Else 
    If Label1.Text = "3" And Label2.Text = "3" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + mille Else 
    If Label1.Text = "4" And Label2.Text = "4" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + mille Else 
    If Label1.Text = "5" And Label2.Text = "5" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + mille Else 
    If Label1.Text = "6" And Label2.Text = "6" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + mille Else 

    If Label2.Text = "1" And Label3.Text = "1" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + mille Else 
    If Label2.Text = "2" And Label3.Text = "2" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + mille Else 
    If Label2.Text = "3" And Label3.Text = "3" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + mille Else 
    If Label2.Text = "4" And Label3.Text = "4" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + mille Else 
    If Label2.Text = "5" And Label3.Text = "5" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + mille Else 
    If Label2.Text = "6" And Label3.Text = "6" Then TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + mille Else 
    TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) - cinqcent

    If TextBox1.Text < 500 Then
        MsgBox("Game Over")
        Me.Close()
    End If

    Label5.Text = "You Won: $"


    If Label1.Text = "1" And Label2.Text = "1" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $1000"
    If Label1.Text = "2" And Label2.Text = "2" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $1000"
    If Label1.Text = "3" And Label2.Text = "3" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $1000"
    If Label1.Text = "4" And Label2.Text = "4" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $1000"
    If Label1.Text = "5" And Label2.Text = "5" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $1000"
    If Label1.Text = "6" And Label2.Text = "6" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $1000"

    If Label2.Text = "1" And Label3.Text = "1" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $1000"
    If Label2.Text = "2" And Label3.Text = "2" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $1000"
    If Label2.Text = "3" And Label3.Text = "3" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $1000"
    If Label2.Text = "4" And Label3.Text = "4" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $1000"
    If Label2.Text = "5" And Label3.Text = "5" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $1000"
    If Label2.Text = "6" And Label3.Text = "6" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $1000"

    If Label1.Text = "1" And Label2.Text = "1" And Label3.Text = "1" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $10,000"
    If Label1.Text = "2" And Label2.Text = "2" And Label3.Text = "2" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $10,000"
    If Label1.Text = "3" And Label2.Text = "3" And Label3.Text = "3" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $10,000"
    If Label1.Text = "4" And Label2.Text = "4" And Label3.Text = "4" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $10,000"
    If Label1.Text = "5" And Label2.Text = "5" And Label3.Text = "5" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $10,000"
    If Label1.Text = "6" And Label2.Text = "6" And Label3.Text = "6" Then Label5.Text = "You Won: $10,000"



    If Label1.Text = "1" And Label2.Text = "1" And Label3.Text = "1" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Big_Win, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label1.Text = "2" And Label2.Text = "2" And Label3.Text = "2" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Big_Win, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label1.Text = "3" And Label2.Text = "3" And Label3.Text = "3" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Big_Win, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label1.Text = "4" And Label2.Text = "4" And Label3.Text = "4" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Big_Win, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label1.Text = "5" And Label2.Text = "5" And Label3.Text = "5" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Big_Win, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label1.Text = "6" And Label2.Text = "6" And Label3.Text = "6" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Big_Win, AudioPlayMode.Background)

    If Label1.Text = "1" And Label2.Text = "1" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CoinWin, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label1.Text = "2" And Label2.Text = "2" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CoinWin, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label1.Text = "3" And Label2.Text = "3" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CoinWin, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label1.Text = "4" And Label2.Text = "4" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CoinWin, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label1.Text = "5" And Label2.Text = "5" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CoinWin, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label1.Text = "6" And Label2.Text = "6" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CoinWin, AudioPlayMode.Background)

    If Label2.Text = "1" And Label3.Text = "1" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CoinWin, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label2.Text = "2" And Label3.Text = "2" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CoinWin, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label2.Text = "3" And Label3.Text = "3" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CoinWin, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label2.Text = "4" And Label3.Text = "4" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CoinWin, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label2.Text = "5" And Label3.Text = "5" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CoinWin, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    If Label2.Text = "6" And Label3.Text = "6" Then My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CoinWin, AudioPlayMode.Background)





    PictureBox5.Visible = False

    If Label1.Text = "1" And Label2.Text = "1" And Label3.Text = "1" Then PictureBox5.Visible = True
    If Label1.Text = "2" And Label2.Text = "2" And Label3.Text = "2" Then PictureBox5.Visible = True
    If Label1.Text = "3" And Label2.Text = "3" And Label3.Text = "3" Then PictureBox5.Visible = True
    If Label1.Text = "4" And Label2.Text = "4" And Label3.Text = "4" Then PictureBox5.Visible = True
    If Label1.Text = "5" And Label2.Text = "5" And Label3.Text = "5" Then PictureBox5.Visible = True
    If Label1.Text = "6" And Label2.Text = "6" And Label3.Text = "6" Then PictureBox5.Visible = True




End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement delays, you would need to move some of your code to the `Timer`'s `Tick` event: On the first `Tick`, show the first number, show the second number on the second `Tick`, and show the third number and the result on the third `Tick`, then stop the `Timer`.

You would need to keep a form-global variable to count how many times the `Timer` has `Tick`ed since the button was pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use Import System.Threading

Thread.sleep(500)

1000 equivalent to 1s

This might you need for that...